# How to properly create a C# WinUI project in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I've been trying to create a new WinUI project. I prepared the development environment following the [MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022) and created the new project with `Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)` template.
Following code runs without any exception.

```
<Window
    x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

However after adding a new `BlankWindow1` window and opening it with this code the app breaks with `kernelbase.pdb not loaded` error. I suspect that I've missed something in creating a project/setting up dev environment, because some time ago I've been using the same code without problems. However after doing it several time I still can't see any mistakes on my side.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window
    x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
namespace App1
{

    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BlankWindow1 window1 = new BlankWindow1();
            window1.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

`App1.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>App1</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="BlankWindow1.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22000.194" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
       Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
       package has not yet been restored -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnablePreviewMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="BlankWindow1.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you currently can't create more than one window in WinUi3, see
[here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5289) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5135). It's mentioned that it is possible in the preview versions of the Windows App SDK.